# Symfony2 DomCrawler Link

Tags: symfony, hyperlink, web-crawler

I'm using Symfony2 DOMCrawler. I have a link on page. I want to go thru the link and crawl some content there. How can I do it? LEt the code be like this

```
<a href="www.example.com">Go there</a>
```

I know about `$crawler->selectLink('Go there')->link();`

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you are looking for something like :

```
$link = $crawler->filter('a[id="fabulous_id"]')->attr('href');
$crawler = $client->request('GET',$link);
```

look [DomCrawler Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/dom_crawler.html) for informations

Comment: I find this to be the best solution in case your links are buttons that contain no text, for example iconic buttons.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for `click()` method.

```
$link = $crawler->selectLink('Go there')->link();
$crawler = $client->click($link);
```

You should read [this documentation chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#your-first-functional-test) more careful